# Why the event did not cause an endless loop?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, event-bubbling, event-propagation

```js
var domInner = document.querySelector('#inner')
var domWrapper = document.querySelector('#wrapper')
domInner.onclick = innerHandler
function innerHandler () {
  console.log('inner')
}
domWrapper.onclick = wrapperHandler
function wrapperHandler () {
  // setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('wrapper')
    domInner.click()
  // }, 1000)
}
domInner.click()
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  wrapper
  <div id="inner">
    inner
  </div>
</div>
```

As we can see ,the `domInner.click()` in function wrapperHandler did not triggered the click event of domInner.

I used to think it will, and the click event of domInner will propagate to domWrapper, so this may cause an endless loop.

But it didn't. So, what's the reason?

After I opened the setTimeout, it would happen.

Why the `domInner.click()` in function wrapperHandler did not triggered the click event of domInner again？And why the event did not cause an endless loop?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you manually click on your inner element, you'll notice that it causes your logs to fire twice. Once for the actual click element, then again for the "simulated" one you triggered with `element.click()`.

Why doesn't it keep looping? Well, it looks like the "simulated" click can only be emitted once per element per [event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop) iteration. Attempts to emit it again from the same element in the same iteration will be ignored. The reason it allows it when you put the `setTimeout` in there is because `setTimeout` puts it on a later event loop iteration.

This appears to be a feature built in to the `element.click` method, probably with the explicit purpose of preventing such infinite loops. Unfortunately the [documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click) isn't particularly detailed, and I'm not sure where else to dig to confirm.